# How to calculate the ICC (intra-class correlation coefficient) from a coxme() object

Tags: r, multi-level, survival

For model:

```
fit1 <- coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + (1|area), data=df)
```

I need to calculate the ICC which is the random effect variance / (random effect variance + residual variance). I can see the random effect variance in the output of summary(fit1), but where is the residual variance? Or is there a simpler way of calculating the ICC?

Comment: I’ve never seen ICC used in this type of model. Can you provide any links to discussions of this measure being derived from such a model.